# Powershell: How to do a Select-String search with an -Exclude for multiple lines of text in another file

Tags: powershell-3.0, select-string

**Project:** I have a log file that is being added to continuously. In this log file on occasion an error (error always includes with "Unable to import" and a unique ID) is added. I need to be alerted by email when this error is added to the log file.

**Current status of project:** I have the script (it is scheduled to run every 15 minutes) scanning through the log file with Select-String and if it finds this error(s) it adds it to a separate text file named alert-(Get-Date).txt. At the end of the PS script the alert.txt file is emailed to me.

**Problem:** A new log file is created daily, so my script only scans through that file. The problem is once it finds an error, every subsequent scan sends me an alert for the error(s) I am already aware of. I want subsequent alerts to only contain NEW errors.

**Current attempt to solve problem**
Here is what a sample error looks like in the log file:

```
 1/29/2015 13:38:45 1/29/2015 13:38:45  Sales Order User Import     Unable to import OHDR_2785_228038_01292015.txt due to required files missing. Files are being removed from current directory to suspense directory.
```

I've added to the script the means to extract the unique ID of the error in log file. In this case it is 2785. This ID and other ID's of errors are added to another text file name oldAlerts.txt. So the contents look like this:

```
2785
1182
1353
1555
```

I am wanting to add to my script a way to exlude these lines for the Select-String results. Here is my Select-String so far:

```
Get-ChildItem \txtforerp\Import\Log | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date)-$ts -AND $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date)} | select-string -Pattern "Unable to import" | Out-File $path\"$alert.txt"
```

How can I use the ID's in the oldAlert.txt file as a filter to ensure only new errors are added to the alert. 
I am open to using other approaches if mine is not a best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [negative assertion lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to exclude any line that was already reported. Also, it should be easy to identify new IDs with Select-String too:

```
Get-ChildItem \txtforerp\Import\Log | Where{ $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date)-$ts } | 
    Select-String "Unable to import OHDR_(?!$($ids -join '|'))(\d{4})" | 
    Select-Object Filename, Line, { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

In this code `$ids` represents list of previously identified IDs.
BTW: I removed this check:

```
$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date)
```

It doesn't seem reasonable to check if files were not modified in future...?

Comment: This works. Thanks for the help and thanks for introducing me to regular expressions. Until now I had never heard of it. I find that tutorial you linked to in your post to be very interesting.